# Field not rewritten even though "Hide rewriting if empty" not selected

Tags: views

Simplified situation:

- A view includes fields `first_name` and `last_name`.
- `first_name` is marked "Exclude from display".
- `last_name` has the label *Full name* (which becomes the column heading in the view).
- `last_name` has "Rewrite the output of this field" checked and the rewrite text `[first_name](space)[last_name]`.
- `last_name` has neither "Hide if empty" nor "Hide rewriting if empty" checked in "No Results Behavior".
- Records with both `first_name` and `last_name` or only `last_name` show properly in the *Full name* column.
- Records with only `first_name` (i.e. empty `last_name`) show nothing.

Seems Drupal should rewrite the field for records with no `last_name` to show `first_name` since there is a specific "Hide rewriting if empty" checkbox that is not checked. Is this expected behavior? Or might there be a module interfering with things?

Comment: I think there's another "Hide Empty Fields" setting under Format settings.. Try there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Niall Murphy. I'm not sure where the "Format settings" you refer to are ... which may be part of my problem!

Comment: I mean the settings for "Unformatted" or "Table" etc. But I'm not sure about the setting as I'm not near a computer.

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't understand why Drupal doesn't behave as I posit in my original question, I have found a solution. It is to use `[first_name]` as the `No results text`. If the last name is empty, the no results text is used, and the first name is displayed. If the last name is non-empty, the rewrite results are used, and the first and last names are displayed. Kind of roundabout, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

It would be hard to debug without having access to code.

Can you please try the following.

- Add two fields first_name and last_name
- Both fields should be marked as exclude from display
- Both fields should have Hide if empty and Hide rewriting if empty
- Add a new field Global: Custom Text (Full name)
- Rewrite the field to include first_name and last_name

Let me know how you go.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion @Ash U. To simplify, I omitted the fact that I'm using Views Data Export with this view. I tried using a Global field, but Views Data Export ignores Global fields when it exports, so that solution doesn't seem ideal for me.